# Two way syncing from local xml file up to sql server db

Tags: wpf, xml, web-services, sql-server-2008

I know when it comes to syncing, a lot of people would say to use a sqlCE and sync it up to the central db. My app is made already using raw xml to save my data(lightweight). My wpf app stores data locally not needing internet on a raw xml file. I'm trying to find the best way (approach) to sync local xml up to my sql server. My goal is to sync the local xml file up with the central db and update the central dbs data, as well as pulling down updated data and updating to my local xml. Hopefully I'm being clear with my question. I've never used web services before so any help or point of direction would be appreciated. Would using the Sync framework work for this?

Comment: If you are going to do it directly then would go WCF over web service.  It manual or synch framework really depends on the nature of the data and the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronizing data is not a trivial task. Have a look at the [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx). I don't know if it supports XML out of the box but you could probably implement a suitable provider.

One word of warning - even synchronizing several SQL Server [Express|CE] databases, something supported out of the box, requires quite a bit of work to get it working.

Comment: well right, nothing rarely works out of the box. But I've read syncing a SQLCE with another sql db is easier than raw xml to a sql db. Everything breaks down to xml eventually so it's def possible. Like you said its going to take some work